# check a radio box from mysql data with function

Tags: php, mysql, function, radio-button

I'm trying to build an edit page for editing my Previous Posts
so when i click edit link in front of a post it sends post id to edit.php
now here is my problem i want to check a radio box in edit page that shows my current post's category
I have a function like this:

```
function category($name,$postid){
if( $name == $postid)
    {
        return "checked";   
    }
}
```

in edit.php

```
$postid=$_GET['postid']
$query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *FROM category");
    while($s=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    echo 
'<table width="200" border="1">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>'.$s['category_name'].'</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="post_category" value="'.$s['category_name'].'" '.category($s['id'],$postid).'></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>';
}
```

but it doesn't check the radio box

Answer (score 0):

You should tell to the PHP to write the return from the function:

**Edit #1**

changing the function to always return something

```
function category($id, $postid) {
    if( $id== $postid)
    {
        return "checked";   
    }

    return null;
}
```

The return will fill the var $checked or with "checked" or with null

```
while($s = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

    $checked = category($s['id'], $postid);

    echo 
        '<table width="200" border="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$s['category_name'].'</td>
                    <td>
                        <input... ' . $checked . '>
                    </td>
                </tr>
             </tbody>
         </table>';
}
```

Comment: can you show me how to put this correctly in my code ?

Comment: Have you debugged the value of $postid? Have you sure that will return checked for any of your categories?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell without actually seeing what is not matching, but from your naming, it looks like you are matching the Id to the Name. If you are matching Id's, then you should use parseInt to make sure you are dealing with integers and comparing data in the same format.

Comment: you are right i have to change this $s['category_name'] with $s['id'] but still doesn't work